# Registering a bunch of custom schemas in IntelliJ

Tags: xml, xsd, intellij-idea

I have a bunch of custom XSD schemas in one of my sub-modules that all other modules depends on.
As I'm about to start some heavy XML development I'd like to know if there is a way to auto-register the namespaces inside these schemas for the IntelliJ IDEA XML editors?

I know that you can register each namespace one by one through the resources settings, but since I have so many namespaces I'm looking for a way to just i.e. register them all at once.

I.e. right click a schema and select "register namespaces" type of thing...

BR

Answer (score 3):

If your schema is visible from internet - then you can set cursor on xmlns element, then press `Alt+Enter`, choose `Fetch external resource`. It should be automatically added as resource.

**UPD.**

Ok, as far as I know you can't add pack of xsd's - only by one.
But I think it can be more comfortable to add them via text editor.

open `userFolder\.IntelliJIdea10\config\options\other.xml`

And find there this tag

```
<component name="com.intellij.javaee.ExternalResourceManagerImpl">
    <resource url="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" location="D:\..."/>
```

HTH

Comment: My schemas are local and my own. I have them in a separate project than the one I'm coding in.